# Technique to remove factors from regression model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

If I have a large number of factors (c. 700) from which I want to generate a predictive time series model, is there a convenient method to "slim" down the number of factors, for instance by ordinally ranking the importance of each factor and then take the top 20?

What is best practice to achieve this result?

Comment: by factors you mean parameters/variables?

Comment: An important question is _why_ you want to do this. In many cases, you really don’t. So why?

Comment: yes exactly, parameters. As for why, a lot of the data does not contain price predictive information, so I'd like to determine which factors can be discarded. Cheers